# How do I use column name as variable instead of hard-typed

Tags: c#, linq

My code to access the database is..

```
using (MyDataContext target = DataContextFactory<MyDataContext>.GetDataContext())
{
    var table_orders = from tab in target.Orders
                       select tab;

    var cols = table_orders.First();

    var colNames = (from property in cols.GetType().GetProperties()
                    select property.Name).ToList();

    string[] fieldvalues;
    foreach (var row in table_orders)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var col in colNames)
        {
           var fieldvalues[i] = row.______.ToString(); <here I need to use 'col' variable not the hard typed property i.e., Order_Id, Order_Desc etc.
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish it? I am trying to read the table without hard-typed column names and load each row into string array.  If there is any other way also let me know.

Comment: you loose the support of the compiler if you do that.

Comment: Why do you **want** to do that? I smell an XY problem.

Comment: I understand.  But I have a need to read each row without column names.  Is there any other way?

Comment: If you need an array of field values (why though?) you should use a DbConnection/Command/Reader, not LINQ-to-SQL.